# if data matches listview is checked in android

Tags: android

first json array

```
{"DDL":[{"Id":2,"name":"ICE FRUITS"},{"Id":3,"name":"DOSA HUT"},{"Id":4,"name":"ELEGENCE"}]}
```

Second json array

```
{"DDL":[{"Id":2,"name":"ICE FRUITS"},{"Id":3,"name":"DOSA HUT"}]}
```

main xml

```
         <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:dividerHeight="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/branchelist">
```

Adapter class xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"

    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/branchuser"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want listview item is checked if second json array value is present in first json array

```
public class UserDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
SessionManager session;
ImageView admindpedit;
String adminid="";
ListView branch;
ArrayList<BranchModel> branchArrayList;
BranchUserAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_user);
    branch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.branchelist);

    branchArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new BranchUserAdapter(getApplicationContext(),     R.layout.branches_checkbox, branchArrayList);

    branch.setAdapter(adapter);

    firstJson();
    secondJson();
 }
public void firstJson() {
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    String url = "http://zamzamapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Branches";
    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserDetails.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Branches...");
    pDialog.show();

    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    JSONObject json;
                    APIResponse apiResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response, APIResponse.class);
                    branchArrayList.clear();
                    branchArrayList.addAll(apiResponse.getDDL());
                    pDialog.hide();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();







                    pDialog.hide();
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("", response);


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(UserDetails.this,
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pDialog.hide();
            // hide the progress dialog

        }
    }) {

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_obj);
}

 publicvoid secondJson()
    {


    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    String url = "http://emservices.azurewebsites.net/Employee.asmx/Login";




    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
               JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            // JSONObject data=obj.getJSONObject("DDL");
                String obj1=obj.getString("name") ;
                               String obj2=obj.getString("Id") ;





            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }




            pDialog.hide();
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, response);


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // hide the progress dialog

        }
    }) {

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_obj);
}
```

In adapter class

```
     public class BranchUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BranchModel> {
     public ArrayList<BranchModel> EmployeesList;
    boolean[] itemChecked;

    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;
    private Context mContext;

    public BranchUserAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<BranchModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        EmployeesList = objects;
        this.mContext = context;


    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            // new 

            holder.branchcheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            holder.branch = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.branchuser);

       holder.branchcheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    BranchModel planet = (BranchModel) cb.getTag();
                    planet.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
            v.setTag(holder);
            holder.branchcheck.setTag(EmployeesList.get(position));

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).branchcheck.setTag(EmployeesList.get(position));
            holder.branchcheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        }


        BranchModel Employees = EmployeesList.get(position);


        holder.branch.setText(EmployeesList.get(position).getName());

        // holder.tvHeight.setText("Height: " + actorList.get(position).getHeight());
        // holder.tvSpouse.setText("Spouse: " + actorList.get(position).getSpouse());
        // holder.tvChildren.setText("Children: " + actorList.get(position).getChildren());
        return v;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        public CheckBox branchcheck;
        public TextView branch;



    }

}
```

Comment: Compare Id in BaseAdapter if it matched then show selected

Comment: Simple compare with Ids or name and the set the checkbox checked in your adapter

Comment: i tried but how to compare it..if you need i will show the complete code

Comment: how to compare two json array in one adapter class

Comment: ok @saeed i posted the complete code ..do you have skype id ,i can share the screen to you.

Comment: @ first you have to add one more field BranchModel  class for Check box is checked or not ... inittially set false ... . while compalition time set true if the id of  already exist

Comment: @Saeed ..can you share the code..